# Modificar type text para radio para consulta ajax

Tags: php, ajax

O codigo que eu tenho é este, porem no lugar do type="text" quero que seja tipo radio, e quando eu selecionar um radio do valor exemplo "A" me liste os dados que tem A, por que com o type="text" eu tenho que digitar.

**Index.php**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script>

//função para pegar o objeto ajax do navegador
function xmlhttp()
{
    // XMLHttpRequest para firefox e outros navegadores
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        return new XMLHttpRequest();
    }

    // ActiveXObject para navegadores microsoft
    var versao = ['Microsoft.XMLHttp', 'Msxml2.XMLHttp', 'Msxml2.XMLHttp.6.0', 'Msxml2.XMLHttp.5.0', 'Msxml2.XMLHttp.4.0', 'Msxml2.XMLHttp.3.0','Msxml2.DOMDocument.3.0'];
    for (var i = 0; i < versao.length; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            return new ActiveXObject(versao[i]);
        }
        catch(e)
        {
            alert("Seu navegador não possui recursos para o uso do AJAX!");
        }
    } // fecha for
    return null;
} // fecha função xmlhttp

//função para fazer a requisição da página que efetuará a consulta no DB
function carregar()
{
   a = document.getElementById('busca').value;
   ajax = xmlhttp();
   if (ajax)
   {
       ajax.open('get','busca.php?busca='+a, true);
       ajax.onreadystatechange = trazconteudo; 
       ajax.send(null);
   }
}

//função para incluir o conteúdo na pagina
function trazconteudo()
{
    if (ajax.readyState==4)
    {
        if (ajax.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById('resultados').innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
        }
    }
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
<form id="form1" action="" method="post">
    Busca:  <input type="text" name="busca" id="busca" value="" onkeyUp="carregar()"/>
</form>
<p> </p>
Resultado da busca:
<div id="resultados" style="border:1px solid #CCCCCC; width:200px;">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**busca.php**

```
<?php
    @mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("projeto");

    $busca = $_GET['busca'];

    if($busca != "") {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM categorias WHERE nome_categoria LIKE '%$busca%' ORDER BY nome_categoria ASC ";
        $query = mysql_query($sql);

        //variavel para zebrar as linhas
        $cont = 0;
        while($row = mysql_fetch_object($query)) {
            //faz a diferenciação das cores para as linhas dos resultados
            if($cont %2 ==0) {
                $cor = "#EDEDED";
            } else {
                $cor = "#FFFFFF";
            }
            echo "<div style='background:$cor'>";
            echo $row->id. " - ";
            echo $row->nome_categoria."<br>";
            echo "</div>";
            $cont ++;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Não entendi muito bem. Qual o erro/dúvida que você tem?

Comment: Como eu modifico o type="text" para o para type="radio" e setar um valor para o radio.

Comment: Você pode apenas mudar o tipo do input de `text` para `radio`. Para que eles funcionem corretamente, você deve setar o atributo `name` com um valor igual para o grupo de `radio` que você quer.

Comment: <input type="radio" name="busca" id="busca" value="a" onkeyUp="carregar()"/>
   <input type="radio" name="busca" id="busca" value="b" onkeyUp="carregar()"/>   Assim não pega.